# Extentions and Cogs not working in discord.py v2

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am trying to get export my troll commands in a discord bot i run to a new file, using cogs and extensions. However, the commands do not register, and I'm not sure why. I'll send the code here. (just ignore the weird function launch, it makes more sense when you look at the bot entirely but its spread thought 2k lines. )

```py
#bot.py
import os
import sys
import time
import datetime

import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord import Intents
import assets
import role_counter
from discord.ext import commands
import discord.ext.commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

import git_push
import merit_config
import trolls

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
TOKEN_TEST = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN_TEST')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')
cogs = ['cogs.trolls']


def startup(START):
    global LAUNCH
    global bot

    if START == TOKEN:
        intents = Intents.all()
        bot = commands.Bot(intents=intents, command_prefix='.')
        bot.remove_command('help')
        LAUNCH = TOKEN

startup(TOKEN)

initial_extensions = ['cogs.trolls']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for extension in initial_extensions:
        bot.load_extension(extension)


def main():
    while True:
        bot.run(LAUNCH)
```

````py
#trolls.py
import assets
from discord.ext import commands


class troll_commands(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def troll(self, ctx):
        if ctx.channel.id == '936902313589764146' or '939028644175699968':
            await ctx.send(f"```{assets.troll_command()}```")
        await self.bot.process_commands()


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(troll_commands(bot))
````

I've mirrored every example i can find, it just isn't working and idk why. If I'm missing some code to reporodce please just tell me, ill edit this post.

Comment: Where th did you "mirror" the first code snippet from?

Comment: @3nws Here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/EvieePy/d78c061a4798ae81be9825468fe146be

Comment: Did you enable intents in the dev console?

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs yes, i did. The bot launches with no errors, but the commands simply do not work. I have no error message to go off of.

Comment: Loading extensions is asyncronous now, see the docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/migrating.html#migrating-2-0-commands-extension-cog-async

Comment: Why do you have `__name__ == '__main__'` but then create another main function below it that is never called? Also see the above comment. Make a coroutine named start (using `await client.start`) and then add the cogs in there, running it using `asyncio.get_event_loop()`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version you're currently using but as you're having issues, you need to clarify what sort of error you're getting.

If you're using V2 then you do need to use async for the majority of your code now, here's a migration guide if you would like to take a look: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html.

The main areas that you need to fix are:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for extension in initial_extensions:
        bot.load_extension(extension) # you need to await this


def main(): # you aren't ever calling main
    while True:
        bot.run(LAUNCH)
```

and

```py
def setup(bot): # needs to be async
    bot.add_cog(troll_commands(bot)) # needs to be awaited
```

There are some other things you should reconsider like global vars but this should work for now.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use async and await to be able to add a cog.

You have to async and await the extension loading and running the bot

await bot.load_extension(extension)

```py
async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Command(bot))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).